# Identify first and last event from an event log .net or powershell

Tags: .net, powershell

I am trying to find the first and last event timestamp in offline evtx files. I am trying to use the EventLogReader.Seek Method (SeekOrigin, Int64) with powershell. I know how to find the Events based on event id as below.

```
$reader = [Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader]::new(
    [Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogQuery]::new($eventLogPath,
        [Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.PathType]::FilePath, $query)
)
```

how would I find the first and last events in a query similar to above? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$reader` will read from the oldest to the newest event by default, unless the `ReverseDirection` property on the `EventLogQuery` object is set to `$true`:

```
# create default reader
$queryObject = [Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogQuery]::new($eventLogPath, 'FilePath', $query)
$forwardReader = [Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader]::new($queryObject)

# read oldest event
$oldestEvent = $forwardReader.ReadEvent()

# Now change the query direction and create a new reader
$queryObject.ReverseDirection = $true
$reverseReader = [Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader]::new($queryObject)

# read the newest event
$newestEvent = $forwardReader.ReadEvent()
```

---

There is no need to do any of the above manually though, you can use [the `Get-WinEvent` cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent) instead:

```
$oldestEvent = Get-WinEvent -Path $eventLogPath -FilterXPath $query -MaxEvents 1 -Oldest 
$newestEvent = Get-WinEvent -Path $eventLogPath -FilterXPath $query -MaxEvents 1
```